# How to get json data from service method call to test case using angular2 unit testing with karma-Jasmine?

Tags: json, unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I have trying to get json data from when i calling service method. I got a return object but i didn't get json data. Which part i have to change?

"goods.services.ts"

```
getAllData(): Observable<Product>{

    let jwtTok1 ="Something";
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Token ' + jwtTok1);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body: {} });
    return this.http.get(BASE_URL_GOODS, options)
      .map((res:Response) => {return Observable.of ({type: "success", payload:  res.json().data})})

      .catch(error => this.handleError(error));

}
```

Another is test case file "goods.component.spec.ts"

```
import {
    inject,
  TestBed,fakeAsync,tick
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    BaseRequestOptions,
    ConnectionBackend,
    Http
} from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend,MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
// Load the implementations that should be tested
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AppState } from '../app.service';
import { ActionReducer, Action, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AppStore } from '../models/appstore.model';
import {goodsDescriptionComponent } from './goods-desc.component';
import { goodsService } from '../common/service/goods.service';
import { goodsReducer } from '../common/reducers/goods.reducer';
import {provideStore} from '@ngrx/store';
import { goods} from '../common/models/goods.model';
import { Input } from '@angular/core';

describe('GoodsDescriptionComponent', () => {
  //let store:Store<AppStore>;
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      BaseRequestOptions,
      MockBackend,
      {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: function(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) {
          return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
        },
        deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
      },
      goodsService, provideStore({goodsData: goodsReducer}),goodsDescriptionComponent
    ]}));
it('should url will be same  ', 
    inject(
      [goodsService, MockBackend],
      fakeAsync((service:ProductsService, backend: MockBackend) => {
        backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {


          expect(connection.request.url).toBe(
            'http://localhost:3001/goodsMS/');

        });
        service.getAllData();

        console.log("goods what we got: ",service.getAllData());
      })));
});
```

Getting Response Result is,

[image]

This Response object getting from console in google chrome. Still i can't get correct solution for getting json data from service method call.i can't reach json server. my json server URL is , `"http://localhost:3001/goods"`. please anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said `I got a return object but i didn't get json data`, where did it happen in your code?

Comment: In "goods.component.spec.ts" file, i got a response in "console.log("goods what we got: ",service.getAllData());" The response like, please the above image. @Michael

Comment: Can any one help me.? still, i am struck on this part. the main thing is, can not reach json server.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to set a response on the connection

   ```
   backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
     expect(connection.request.url).toBe(
       'http://localhost:3001/goodsMS/');

     connection.mockRepond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
       body: `{"some":"json", "response":"body"}`
     }));
   });
   ```
2. You need to subscribe to your service call

   ```
   service.getAllData().subscribe((result) => {
     expect(somethingWithData)
   })
   tick()
   ```

   since you are using `fakeAsync`, you need to `tick` to force completion of the asynchronous observable. If you use `async` instead of `fakeAsync`, then you don't need to call `tick`
3. You should not be returning an `Observable` in the service method `map` function. Just return a normal object.

   ```
   .map((res:Response) => {type: "success", payload:  res.json().data})
   ```

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet. But This is not a correct solution for this issue. because i need to validate dynamic 'JsonData" from api call. Your answer willbe used for to validating static jsonData. My problem is i can't get json data from service method(api call).

Comment: Can any one help me.? still, i am struck on this part. the main thing is, can not reach json server.